# Angular HTTP Post Body Not Sending

Tags: angular, http

I'm trying to replicate a successful Postman request that has a single header and a body that is:
[{"attrId":629,"value":["1000"],"unitValue":1,"minValue":"","maxValue":""}]

```
getData() {

  const data = [{'attrId': 629, 'value': ['1000'], 'unitValue': 1, 'minValue': '', 'maxValue': ''}];

  this.http
    .post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', data, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    })
    .subscribe(
      response => console.log(response.toString()), // Success path
            error => this.handleError(error) // error path
    );
  }

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }
 // return an observable with a user-facing error message
  // return throwError(
  //   'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
}
```

I'm getting a 404 response from the server.  I feel like I'm not transmitting the something correctly but it looks ok to me. What's also weird is I don't see anything being sent in the network panel of Chrome dev tools.  The only thing in the console is:

Backend returned code 404, body was: undefined

What am I missing?

[image: Postman request]

Network tab

[image: Network]

Console tab

[image: Console]

I am new to Angular so I could be missing something obvious. The server is pre-existing and I don't have access to it. Edit: I changed to a placeholder REST api that I could test from and got the exact same issue so it's clearly a problem with my code as opposed to the backend. 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Comment: Are you sure you have a `POST` on your server side? Your method says `get`. Did you change your request type on PostMan request type to POST?

Comment: It's definitely post.  Ignore the method name

Comment: No need to set header `application/json`, HttpClient module default set application/json

Comment: I added that because it was necessary via postman.  SHouldn't be the problem though, right?

Comment: Can you add your server side of `POST`? It's `404` because `POST` request type doesn't exists on your server.

Comment: Actually, can you confirm that your POST on your server side is accepting an `Array` or an `Object`? You are sending an `Array`

Comment: Attached an image of what I'm sending via postman that's working

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the chrome network tools for the request you are sending? If you get an error message about back end 404, the request must be sent. Maybe you've got a filter or something in the network tab

Comment: @David I added the images

Comment: That's definitely weird if you don't see the request in the network tab. I'd think it's an invalid request, but it should not give 404 code.... Could you show a console.log of the `error` object in your handler? (with the object expanded). And are you sure about API_URL has the correct value in your code?

Comment: @David I switched to a public test REST API and got the same results. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Comment: I tried your code on stackblitz as is and it works. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1tghg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts  Do you have any interceptors defined somewhere?

Comment: Ugh...@David you are amazing.  There was indeed and interceptor so it was hitting a mock...which didn't have the endpoint defined, hence a 404. If you want to submit that as an answer I'll mark it correct so you get credit. Also, bonus points for that link!!

Answer (score 0):

I think its due to quote miss in JSON data.Try changing the JSON data you are sending like below.

```
const data =[{
"attrId": 629,
"value": ["1000"],
"unitValue": 1,
"minValue": "",
"maxValue": ""
}]
```

And also try to add UTF-8 encoding to content type like below

```
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: So " instead of ' ?

Comment: Yes give it a try.

Comment: Quotation doesn't matter... That's not an issue. I always use single quote on my json data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
getData(data: any) {

let body = JSON.stringify(data);
let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' });

this.http.post<any>(API_URL, body, { headers: headers })
  .subscribe(
        result => { console.log(result); },
        error => { this.handleError(error); },
        () => {});
}
```

On server you need to pick it from body:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IHttpActionResult SomeAction([FromBody]DataClass data)
 {

 }
```

Comment: Not sure what's the difference between this and OP code, you are still sending the same data. Also what made you assume he's using asp.net webapi? It wasn't stated anywhere he's using that.

Comment: @penleychan Thanks for downvote. It was my lucky guess that he is using wab api.

Comment: You mean you assume he is. He didn't state he is using it anywhere.

Comment: @penleychan it doesn't matter. If my comment helps him, I will be happy. Chill out :-)

Comment: @easycheese can you post your server side so we can see what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Node/Express backend,
make sure you have

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```